# How to use d-flex justify-content-between in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a psd like this and I want to design like this.

[image: psd]

But I see this demo

[image: demo]

```
<div class="card rounded">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="float-right">
            <h5>مشاوره خرید چرا مطلاعه</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="float-left">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success">خرید</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning">در حال انجام</a>
            <span>5 ساعت پیش</span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="float-right">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/51/f6/fb/51f6fb256629fc755b8870c801092942.jpg" class="mr-1 rounded-circle w-25 h-25">
            <span>2 نفر به درخواست شما پاسخ داده اند</span>
        </div>
        <div class="float-left">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success">حدف</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning">جزییات شما</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whatever I thought, How this is done, I don't know.

I am creating a simple Express web server that serves a landing page made with bootstrap, but I can't get any Flexbox examples to work.

Answer (score 1):

can use default bootstrap classes,

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 text-left">left content</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 text-right">right content</div>

for v-align, use class "align-self-center"
```

Comment: Ok , how to add border class and hr tag?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/

Comment: <hr/> for hr tag

Comment: I updated my post. And I use float-right, But my poblem did not solve my problem.